# How to append cell values of a particular column in one excel sheet as new unique columns into another excel sheet

Tags: excel, merge, dataset

I have two excel sheets, Player_Records and Match_Records, with one common column named Match_ID in both.

The Player_Records sheet contain career records of multiple players. The Player_ID column identifies the player but not uniquely since there are multiple records (each record has details regarding the results of a particular match) for each player. The Match_ID column identifies the match but also not uniquely since many players have an entry for the same match.

[image: Player_Records sheet]
***Player_Records sheet***

The Match_Records sheet contain records of every match played and the Match_ID column uniquely identifies each match.

[image: Match_Records sheet]
***Match_Records sheet***

What I want to achieve:

Append each (unique) player from the Player_Records file as a column into the Match_Records file so that a record in the Match_Records file has a column for each player (regardless of whether they played in that match).

When this is done, the Match_Records file will have a column for each player and the cell value of those columns can be boolean to indicate whether that player was part of that particular match.

How can I do this?

Comment: Create an extra column with Match IDs and Player IDs toghether in the Player_Records sheet. Create the extra columns in the Match_Records sheet with the Player IDs. For each cells of those columns search if the combination of the Match ID of that row and the Player ID of that column is in the Match ID-Player ID column of the Player_Records sheet.

Comment: Thanks, I've been attempting this but I don't know how to do the last step, how do I perform a search like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1: create a colum with Match IDs and Player IDs**

Assuming that in sheet Player_Records the column G is avaiable, put in cell G1 this formula:

`=F1 & " | " & D1`

Then drag it to the end of the list. If you did it correctly, the cell G86 should return the value `914567 | ODI # 4072`. Clearly it contains the player ID, the " | " marker and the match ID. Attention: if the marker is likely to appear in a player or match ID, use a different marker.

**Step 2: create the players' columns**

You could manually write all the players ID, but with many players that would be stupid. It's better to use some formulas. Assuming that in sheet Player_Records the column H is avaiable, put in cell H1 this formula:

`=IF(F2=F1,"",F2)`

Then drag it to the end of the list. It will give you a list with many blank-looking cells and the players ID reported once each. If all the players ID are just numbers and assuming that in sheet Match_Records the columns from G and left from that are avaiable, put in cell G1 this formula:

`=SMALL(Player_Records!$H:$H,CELL("col",G1)-6)`

Then drag it **horizontally** until you reach a column where the result given is a `#NUM!` error. Clear any `#NUM!` error and copy-paste the **values** of the rest of the cells you've just filled with the formula. At this point those cells contains the players IDs as values, so you can clear the column H in the Player_Records sheet because it's of no use now. If the players IDs are not all numbers, this method won't work (but there are others).

**Step 3: search for Match ID-Player ID combination**

In the sheet Match_Records in the cell G2 put this formula:

`=IF(COUNTIF(Player_Records!$G:$G,G$1&" | "&$E2)>0,TRUE,FALSE)`

Then drag it vertically and horizontally to the ends of the list. This formula basically check if in the G column of the Player_Records sheet (the column with player and match IDs combined) is any occurrence of the combination of the player ID of the given column and the match ID of the given row with the marker " | " in between them (if you have used a different marker, change the formula accordingly). If any occurence is present, the formula returns TRUE; otherwise it returns FALSE. You can change the outcome (for example with 1 and 0 or "played" and "") by editing the formula.